# Sms ContentObserver onChange() function execute 3 times

Tags: java, android, contentobserver

Sms ContentObserver class function on change execute 3 times how to manage 1 time.

How to gwt one sms on the onchange() function   .

ContentObserver in onchange() function why execute 3 time why this function execute 3 time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.